# Navigation bar items disappears when close and re opne my app xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbar

I am working with an app with two different screens, one of them is the login with qr (same situation as whatsapp) which when doing authentication I do an async push to go to a tabbed page with several different tabs, which in the xaml code I ordered him not to draw the back button, in addition to adding an item toolbar (like the one below) with which I will have an app logout button, when I only go out to see another app and reopen, the title and the tool bar item disappears, also the back button returns. If I press any of the tabs items that take me to a detail screen and return to the initial screen, the toolbar is as it should.

What is going on?

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:behaviorsPack="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Class="NetMobile.Views.Organization"
            NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
            Title="{Binding Title}">
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="tiLogout" Order="Primary" Icon="exit.png" Priority="1" Clicked="TiLogout_Clicked"  />
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: you shouldn't nest a TabbedPage inside of a NavigationPage

Comment: You would better change the **MainPage** instead of pushing navigation .